# CSS flexitem's paddingleft property not working on page refresh

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Chrome not rendering the padding-left on page refresh, but works when I uncheck and check the padding-left property using chrome development tools. Could someone help me understand whats happening here.

Chrome version: Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)

problematic code section:

```
                    <div class='header-col3'>
                        <div class='header-menu-container'>
                            <div class='menu-list'>
                                <div class='search-box'><div></div></div>
                                <div class='share-box'><div></div></div>
                                <div class='cart-box'><div></div></div>
                                <div class='login-box'><div></div></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Below is my full html & css code

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cricdl - header</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='./static/css/main.css'/>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Helvetica"> -->
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Helvetica+Neue|Helvetica"> -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id='header-banner'>
            <div class='header-container'>
                <div class='header-container-flex'>
                    <div class='header-col1'>
                        <div class='header-logo-container'>
                            <div class='dummy-logo'></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='header-col2'>
                        <div class='header-nav-container'>
                            <nav>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span>Players</span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span>Teams</span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span>Series</span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span>Stats</span>
                                </a>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='header-col3'>
                        <div class='header-menu-container'>
                            <div class='menu-list'>
                                <div class='search-box'><div></div></div>
                                <div class='share-box'><div></div></div>
                                <div class='cart-box'><div></div></div>
                                <div class='login-box'><div></div></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

css code:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

.dummy-logo {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

#header-banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba( 0,0,0,0.08 );
}

.header-container {
    padding-top: 1.1%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.header-container-flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.header-col1, .header-col3 {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.header-col2 {
    flex: 2;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.header-nav-container nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #505050;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 10%;
}

.menu-list {
    display: flex;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

.menu-list > div {
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
    padding-left: 10%;
}

.menu-list > div > div{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: tomato;
    border-radius: 2px;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
}
```

[image: on unchecking and checking padding-left property using chrome development tools]

[image]

Comment: seems to work if you use margin instead of padding: https://www.bootply.com/tcSBlkj1Wq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it working, its because ure using display flex when the .menu-list > div has no width, and then giving them a padding.

I used display inline block see here.

```
.menu-list {
    font-size: 0; /* to remove the extra PX that display: inline block generates */
}

.menu-list > div {
    display: inline-block; /* change this */
    padding-left: 10%;
}
```

**EDIT**
Now i see that the height is not 20px there is a fix:

```
.header-col3 {
    border: none;
}

.menu-list {
    font-size: 0; /* to remove the extra PX that display: inline block generates */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.menu-list > div {
    display: inline-block; /* change this */
    padding-left: 10%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
}

.menu-list > div > div{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: tomato;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: block;
}
```